# Process terminated with status -1073741510

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list

I ve written a C++ program to **insert into a sorted linked list** - gives the error : **Process terminated with status -1073741510** 
I have used double pointers here to access the head node.
NO other errors in the program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;    
};
 void ins(int d,node** head)
{
   node* temp=new node;
   node* prev=new node;
   temp->next=NULL;
   temp->data=d;
   if(head==NULL)
    {
        *head=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node* ptr=*head;
        while(ptr!=NULL && ptr->data<d)
        {   prev=ptr;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        prev->next=temp;
        temp->next=ptr;    
    }  
}
void print(node* head)
{
    node* ptr=head;int i=0;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
   {
    cout<<i<<" "<<ptr->data<<" ";
    i++;
    ptr=ptr->next;
  }
}
int main()
{
 node* head=NULL;
 ins(4,&head);
 ins(10,&head);
 ins(9,&head);
 print(head);
 return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Such a C style code. You are loosing memory in each ins by    node* prev=new node; and than not using it. However it is working for me without crash.

Comment: @KIIV To save the previous node,there ain't any other way right?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://cpp.sh/56sv ? But in C++ there is usually used "container class" encapsulating whole interface. No C-style procedural programming like this...

Comment: @KIIV yeah thats' a quick code !! thank  you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake in `if (head == NULL)` it should be `if (*head == NULL)` as head shouldn't be null at all. But this shouldn't cause process termination.

Comment: Thank you @KIIV !!